# Moving custom MySQL query into PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I wrote a query, and it works directly through MySQL on the server like this:

> CREATE TABLE tmp_1 (user1 varchar(255), pid int(11));INSERT INTO `famgallery`.`tmp_1` SET `user1` = (SELECT `title` FROM `cpg15x_albums` WHERE `aid` = (SELECT aid FROM cpg15x_pictures WHERE pid=(select max(pid) from cpg15x_pictures))); 
>       UPDATE `famgallery`.`tmp_1` SET `pid` = (SELECT MAX(pid) FROM cpg15x_pictures)
>       ;  UPDATE cpg15x_pictures f, tmp_1 t SET f.user1 = t.user1 WHERE f.pid = t.pid; DROP TABLE tmp_1;

The problem comes by trying to move it into PHP:

> cpg_db_query("CREATE TABLE tmp_1 (user1 varchar(255), pid int(11));INSERT INTO `famgallery`.`tmp_1` SET `user1` = (SELECT `title` FROM `cpg15x_albums` WHERE `aid` = (SELECT aid FROM cpg15x_pictures WHERE pid=(select max(pid) from cpg15x_pictures))); 
>       UPDATE `famgallery`.`tmp_1` SET `pid` = (SELECT MAX(pid) FROM cpg15x_pictures)
>       ;  UPDATE cpg15x_pictures f, tmp_1 t SET f.user1 = t.user1 WHERE f.pid = t.pid; DROP TABLE tmp_1;")

After a day's worth of experimentation the application keeps giving me this critical error:

> mySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near:
>
> ```
> 'INSERT INTO cpg15x_tmp_1 SET `user1` = (SELECT `title` FROM cpg15x_albums WHERE ' at line 1.  File: /home/content/47/9243147/html/family/include/functions.inc.php - Line: 270
> ```

I'm starting to think that there is a conflict somewhere in the application code, because I can't understand why it works fine directly on the server but won't work in PHP after this amount of tinkering.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

`cpg_db_query` is built into the application.  As far as I can tell it performs the same operation as `mysqli_query`.

Related files:

- http://www.mconchicago.com/upload.txt
- http://www.mconchicago.com/init.inc.txt

Comment: Are you sure `cpg_db_query()` allows multiple querys? you might need to split it up into multiple `cpg_db_query()`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpg_db_query` is a wrapper around `mysql_query`; and you that will only run a single query - you're trying to run multiple queries there.

If you want to do this, you'll have to break it up into different queries, and run them separately:

```
cpg_db_query("CREATE TABLE cpg15x_tmp_1 (user1 varchar(255), pid int(11))");
cpg_db_query("INSERT INTO cpg15x_tmp_1 SET user1 = (SELECT title FROM cpg15x_albums WHERE aid = (SELECT aid FROM cpg15x_pictures WHERE pid = (select max(pid) from cpg15x_pictures)))");
cpg_db_query("UPDATE famgallery.cpg15x_tmp_1 SET pid = (SELECT MAX(pid) FROM cpg15x_pictures)");
cpg_db_query("UPDATE cpg15x_pictures f, cpg15x_tmp_1 t SET f.user1 = t.user1 WHERE f.pid = t.pid");
cpg_db_query("DROP TABLE cpg15x_tmp_1");
```

`mysqli_*` has [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), which is the only way I know of to run multiple SQL queries using a single call.

Comment: even mysqli's multiquery will still fire off individual queries. it just looks like a single query() call to the code.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Splitting it up did the trick.  I wasn't aware of this limitation.

Comment: Thanks to the other commentators as well.  Everyone's input was helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of mysqli or cpg_db, but I know that mysql doesn't support multiple queries in one submission. So to do say 5 queries you'd have to do 5 mysql_query.

I'd check to make sure that cpg_db supports more than 1 query at a time.